# Time zone is being overwritten chattr +i

Tags: php, cpanel

Currently the time zone is being overwritten, that is, we edit the file:

`/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/56/etc/php.ini`

Then we assign:

```
chattr + i /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/56/etc/php.ini
```

We are changing this code from php.ini

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Santiago
```

But it is also overwritten periodically, cPanel skips this configuration and overwrites it, could you tell us why this happens.

Comment: One of the many reasons cPanel sucks. You likely have to change it somewhere in cPanel itself - getting overwritten presumably means it's periodically resetting that file.

Comment: So, this doesn't have any solution ?

Comment: "Ditch cPanel" would be my recommended solution, as it'll save you a lot of trouble down the road. If not, contact cPanel support and ask them how it's done. Presumably there's a way, but if my memory of cPanel is accurate, it's going to be a weird convoluted one.